# Cortex-A9 , Arm Compiler 5 (DS built int) , Read CNTFRQ register

Tags: arm, inline-assembly, cortex-a

I try to read CNTFRQ register with inline assembly code.
I use the following:

1. Arria V soc evaluation board
2. Bare-Metal app
3. Arm Compiler 5 (DS built in)

I encountered two issues:

1. I tried to use "regular" syntax which I saw in other places as well and it didn't work.

   ```
    static uint32_t freq = 0;
    __asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c14, c0, 0" : "=r" (freq));
   ```

I don't know what is wrong with this syntax:

2. I tried another syntax:

   ```
   __asm
   {
       mrc p15, 0, freq, c14, c0, 0
   }
   ```

Now the code compiles but I have two problems:

- There is no volatile statement
- When I execute this asm code via debugger it halts when it reaches the asm code and that's it (I don't see the print value and can't continue to next step or running the debugger)

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: @MikeCAT I replaced the OP's images by text.

Comment: did you try real assembly language first then try to inline it?

Comment: apologies for the png's. I'll remember that for next time.

Comment: no I didn't try it since I don't know how to do it. The inline option is shorter for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although many compilers use GNU's inline assembly syntax (what you call "regular syntax"), the syntax of inline assembly is not standardized and many compilers use a different syntax.

Obviously, your compiler is one of them.

> There is no `volatile` statement

You must check the compiler manual for the correct syntax of inline assembly. Maybe the compiler always treats inline assembly the way GNU C/C++ would treat `__asm volatile`.

> When I execute this asm code via debugger it halts when it reaches the asm code and that's it

The `CNTFRQ` register is not mentioned in the Cortex-A9 manual. Are you sure that this register exists on your CPU?

Comment: I'll check it again. in case it doesn't exists, maybe you know how can I get the cpu frequency? (maybe other register)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
It turns out that the cortex-A9 doesn't have the CNTFRQ register.
So that's the answer for my original question.

Maybe you know how I can get the CPU freq in cortex-A9? which register I can read?

Thanks

Comment: *Maybe you know how I can get the CPU freq in cortex-A9? which register I can read?* - You should ask that as a new question if you really want anyone else to answer it.  If you'd included it as part of the original question here, that could have worked, but it's better not to edit in new questions after your question already has an answer.  If you do post a new question, link this one as well as asking what to do instead, e.g. [A9 doesn't have a `CNTFRQ` register] (link), how *do* I find the CPU frequency?  Of course, google first to see if it's already answered.

Comment: According to the ARM Reference Manual, "CNTFRQ" is actually nothing else than 32-bits of RAM and the **operating system** must write the clock frequency to this address. On a CPU that has this register, reading the register will return a non-sense value if the OS (or your bare-metal app) did not write the correct value to the register before. In the code that I have seen, the frequency was known during compile time and hard-coded. Example: `#define CPU_FREQUENCY 40000000`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Is there another way which I can check during runtime my CPU freq?